# If the union of linear spans is the span of unions, then one of two spans is a subset of the other

Tags: linear-algebra

If $span(A) \cup span(B)=span(A\cup B)$, then $span(A) \subseteq span(B)$ or $span(B)\subseteq span(A)$.

I can not see way this claim is right

Comment: It is because the union of subspaces is a subspace only if one is included in the other.

Comment: What is A or B, vectors ? but it look strange... If A and B are set, what is the definition of $span(A)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proof by contrapositive.

Suppose that the desired conclusion fails to hold, i.e. neither $span(A)\subseteq span(B)$ nor $span(B)\subseteq span(A)$ holds.  Choose $u\in span(A)\setminus span(B)$, and $v\in span(B)\setminus span(A)$.

Now $u+v\in span(A\cup B)$, yet $u+v\notin span(A)$ and $u+v\notin span(B)$.  Hence $span(A)\cup span(B)\neq span(A\cup B)$.